# Loading a new table into Power BI from SharePoint

Tags: powerbi

I used "Get Data" to load 2 lists into a dataset. The lists were loaded as two tables: table 1 and table 2.
Now I need to load a 3rd list from SharePoint as Table 3 in the Power BI dataset
How do I accomplish this?

Comment: how did you load first 2 tables?

Comment: You can hit the "Get Data" button to add an additional table from any source.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.